# MissingResourceException: не могу найти файл.resources

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.Использую три способа достучаться до Resource Bundle, и все три не работают. Создал на всякий случай package в корне(src) и в папке с классами. Не работает.привожу код:

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("data.properties");
ResourceBundle res = new PropertyResourceBundle(f);
System.out.println(res.getString("ru"));

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources", Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(bundle.getString("ru"));

File file = new File("data.properties");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("data", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
System.out.println(rb.getString("ru"));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папку resources пометьте в идее как Resource Root

Comment: Да спасибо, проблемма была именно в этом. Вынес папку в директорию проекта и пометил, все заработало. Вот рабочий код:         String s = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("resources.properties").getFile();
        File f = new File(s);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());